# Register ViewState for "visible=false" UserControl - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, viewstate

We have a web app(-ish) webform, and we use many custom `UserControl`s. We load a bunch of them in each view, but we don't want them to render, or even pre-render, until we don't have to use them. Then we set `Visible = False` in each control and then we use `Update Panel`s to set it to `True` whenever the control is needed. The control then shows up correctly.

But in the next postback we have a very nasty MAC validation error, and we think it is related to the ASP not updating the viewstate (but I don't know if that's entirely true yet).

The question: Is it possible to know in exactly wich argument the MAC validation is throwing an error? If we're right, and the `ViewState` for the user controls is not being updated in the already sent page, what would be the correct way to do it / workaround for it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since learnt a lot of ASP, so I will clarify my failure points:

> and we think it is related to the ASP not updating the viewstate (but I don't know if that's entirely true yet)

Of course, it's absolutelly `false`. ASP updates the entire `ViewState` on every post back, so there's no way to not update it.

The MAC validation issue occured when we turned on the UserControl (`Visible=true`) because we didn't specify the validation of the events that control performed (performing custom `__doPostBack()`s)

So, the assumption is entirelly incorrect, and the error goes away by simply registering with `RegisterForEventValidation()` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx))